# With Batch, how do I open a CSGO weapon inspecting URL?

Tags: batch-file

So this is the URL for inspecting a weapon in CSGO.

```
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275
```

Whenever I paste this above URL in Chrome's search bar or the Steam's console with "open" command, it works fine, but if I try to run this command with the exact same URL in a bat file:

```
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275
PAUSE
```

NOTHING happens. It won't open it. (With or without giving it the Chrome's parameter)

What could be the reason?

Comment: Actually, I might want to take back my answer. What you've done above should work just as well. What happens when you run that `start` command from within a batch file, and what if you run it directly from the command line? Is it literally true that NOTHING happens?

Comment: @MichaelRatanapintha Okay so I don't know how familiar you are with CS:GO the game, but to be exact what really happens is: If the game doesn't run, the batch file with the command STARTS it. Starting it works fine, but it won't open the Weapon Inspection which it should. The strange thing is that pasting the command to Chrome DOES the Weapon Inspection.
This is really strange. It is supposed to be a Christmas present for my little brother, but it's not a world end if it won't happen, I'll try to find other way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please try this: `Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275`

Comment: @Compo Not working, it only opens Chrome. But thanks man! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just to explain, the first doublequoted argument to the `Start` command is taken as the title, so I have added an empty one. Then, as your URL contained a `%` character, and you're running it from a batch file, that `%20` required escapng, and that is done by doubling it, `%%20`. If it's not working then the issue is with something you've left out, or you've tested my batch file command directly in `cmd.exe` instead!

Comment: @Compo has it right with the %%, though some more tweaks are needed. How I love batch file quoting!

Comment: Oh God, @Compo it works!
I tried
Start "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275
with the escape character % you've said before, but without the empty " " part, and now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular scenario - providing a one-click way for the user to launch a URL - you probably don't want to muck around with batch files at all. Instead, create a shortcut from within the Windows UI:

1. Right-click on an empty area of the desktop
2. New → Shortcut
3. Enter the URL as the shortcut target:  `steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275`

Now you can copy the shortcut (a .url file) around, just like the batch file you were trying to write. And no quoting headaches!

Answer (score 1):

(Answer includes corrections from the esteemed [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo). But see my other answer which fits the original asker's need better.)

Normally, you should only need to pass the URL or URI to the `start` command, and it will launch the default app associated with that URL/URI scheme. You don't need to start Chrome especially. (In fact, your exact command above *doesn't* start Chrome - as seen from `start /?`, quoting the first argument to the `start` command renames the title of the console window started to run the command, and since no such window is needed to launch Steam, the quoted text is thrown away.)

However, your URL includes `%20` in the middle. When executing a batch file - and *only* then - the cmd.exe command shell will eat any `%` percent signs in a command, as part of an ultimately-futile attempt to substitute into each command the command-line arguments passed to the batch file (which are designated as `%1`, `%2`, and so on). This means you have to double the `%` percent sign in your command, which then becomes:

```
start steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275
```

With the doubled `%%`, you can see using Process Explorer or similar that Steam is now launched with the correct URL you intended:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -- "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198142545136A20205093903D7405092239470426275"`

Comment: As your URL contains a `%` character, and you're running it from a batch file, that `%20` requires escaping via doubling it, i.e. `%%20`.